ADF Pipeline Script Activity output - set variables
I have pretty easy select to Azure SQL DB which return 2 rows with 2 attributes. In output it looks like this:
{
    "resultSetCount": 1,
    "recordsAffected": 0,
    "resultSets": [
        {
            "rowCount": 2,
            "rows": [
                {
                    "Name": "Adam",
                    "Surname": "Black"                  
                },
                {
                    "Name": "Richard",
                    "Surname": "Nolan"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],

And I want to Set Variable to get value {"Name":["Adam","Richard"]} but I am not able to achieve it at all.
@activity('Script1').output.resultSets[0].rows[0].Name - does not work as I expected
Any advice, please?

You need to use combination of For-each activity and append variable activity to achieve your requirement.
First create an array variable with no values in the pipeline variables section. Here, I have created two array variables where the second variable is just for showing result and it's not required.

Take a for-each activity and give the rows array @activity('Script1').output.resultSets[0].rows from the Script activity to it and check the Sequential checkbox in this as it preserves the order of the array.

Inside for-each, take an append variable activity and select the array variable that created earlier. Give the expression @item().Name to it. It appends the Name value to the created array in each iteration.

At the end of the for-each the result array will be stored in the mynames array and you can use it in further activities as per your requirement. For just showing the result, I have assigned this array variable to another array variable res_display in a set variable activity after the for-each activity.
Debug the pipeline and you will get the expected array:


big thank you for detailed instruction - it´s working exactly as I want. And i have additional question if I may. I want to use this variable for azure function(python) as an input for body like this "{"Name": ["Rakesh","John"]}" I set variable @concat('"{"Name":',variables('mynames'), '}"') but the output is ""{"Name":["Rakesh","John"]}"" and I am not able to get rid of \ characters.
Thank you so much

If you want to pass it as a string, then there is no need to worry about \ character as it is an escape character for the ". It won't be passed to the function. Only the required string will be passed to the function.

I see ok, that good. And if the expecting json for my function is body call {"Name": ["Rakesh","John"]} but I can see in the input "{"Name": ["Rakesh","John"]}". Can I remove " from beggin and from the end. Or this is something what i can ignore too?

If you want to pass it as string, you can have it. If it should be JSON, you can remove those '' or you can use @json(concat('{"Name":',string(variables(<your_variable_name>)),'}')) function wrap your JSON string. This function converts JSON string into JSON object.

I am getting error "The variable 'OutputJSON' of type 'String' cannot be initialized or updated with value of type 'Object'. The variable 'OutputJSON' only supports values of types 'String'." and i used @json(concat('{"Name":',string(variables('Name')),'}')).
If I understand it correctly input is array, with string(variables(<your_variable_name>)) i will convert it to JSON String, then concat it with  '{"Name":' a with the @json on begging i should get result {"Name": ["Rakesh","John"]} without " "
Is it correct that variable is define as a string? or where i did mistake? Thank you

Then pass the array as string that means remove the @json() function. In your function convert this JSON string to normal JSON.
